# c# WPF TextBox bug when retrieve lines by index?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Simple wpf app here:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="wpf_textbox_of.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_textbox_of"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="5"  Name="txt" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Fire 1!" Click="btn_OnClick" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Fire 2!" Click="btn2_OnClick" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs (omitting using)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 90009; i++)
            sb.AppendLine($"{i}");
        txt.Text = sb.ToString();
    }

    private void btn2_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++)
            sb.AppendLine(txt.GetLineText(150 * i).Trim());
        for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++)
            sb.AppendLine(txt.GetLineText(15000*i).Trim());
        txt.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Run. Click "Fire 1!", then "Fire 2!".

Expected result:

> 150 300 450 600 750 900 15000 30000 45000 60000 75000 90000

But obtain:

> 150 300 450 600 750 900 15001 30002 45003 60004 75004 90005

Checked on MSVS 2017, .net 4.6.1, .net 4.6, .net 4.5.2, .net 4.5, .net 4.
Any workarounds?

Comment: Looking at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e973795d-83a0-4abe-b9b9-ade2a8e485dc/textbox-problems-with-line-indices?forum=wpf) makes me think this is a bug in the wpf textbox that never got fixed

Comment: This is so disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any workarounds?

You could get the lines from the `string` returned from the `Text` property:

```
private void btn2_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = txt.Text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        sb.AppendLine(lines[150 * i].Trim());
    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        sb.AppendLine(lines[15000 * i].Trim());
    txt.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```