# TextBox.GetLineText() returns same text for first and second line

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core, .net-5

This is probably a bug (or I need a nap). Can someone check if I'm missing something here?

`TextBox.GetLineText(0)` and `TextBox.GetLineText(1)` appear to return same text. Here is my TextBox:

[image]

Here is some debug info:

```
Console.Write(TextBox.Text);           // "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ."
Console.Write(TextBox.LineCount);      // 3
Console.Write(TextBox.GetLineText(0)); // "The quick brown fox "
Console.Write(TextBox.GetLineText(1)); // "The quick brown fox "
Console.Write(TextBox.GetLineText(2)); // "jumps over the lazy "
Console.Write(TextBox.GetLineText(3)); // ArgumentOutOfRange exception thrown
```

There is no carriage return or linefeed in the text itself (text is wrapping because of TextBox size).

I'm completely clueless as to why this is happening. This is WPF on top of .NET 5 if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Probably a WPF bug. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788009/c-sharp-wpf-textbox-bug-when-retrieve-lines-by-index

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh: hmmm... good to see that I'm not alone. But this will create serious  problems for me as my app needs to know the X/Y location of each text line in the textbox.

Comment: Also, I find it a huge oversight. You can't ship a `TextBox` that will break on "The quick brown fox".